# Leaving the company; how can I get my personal items back?

Tags: professionalism, communication, resignation

My goal is to hear people’s advice of what I should do instead and if there are special cases to consider.

So to reiterate the question and provide more details:

- I work for company A that serves as a vendor for B onsite at B.
- During COVID we started to work from home but I left some personal items in my drawer (<$100 total value and tax paperwork).
- I’m leaving company A, but my stuff is still with B. When I contact company B, B’s response is to work with A after COVID because they are not shipping personal items right now.
- I proposed that B can ship my items back in the box B is shipping to me to return B’s computer.

I know that working with company A after I leave is a horrible bureaucracy and this most likely  results that I don’t get my stuff back.

During the next few weeks, I’m going to receive boxes such that I can ship each company’s respective computers back to them.

So I thought of a quid-pro-quo where they ship my low-value items to me in return for their high-value items back. But outright saying this is not right.

So the question now becomes, how should I make it clear that they should ship my stuff back because they are getting theirs back?

Comment: My goal is given the situation, to ask for advice as to how to handle my issue. Hopefully my hairbrained question and fattie’s answer can guide people in the future to not do something like this.

Comment: Edited the post because it was phrased in a confusing and distracting way. Now it's more fit for TWP style.

Comment: @DarkCygnus thanks for that.

Comment: @Bluebird no problemo... in the future try to consider your phrasing because the way you framed it here was not the best way to go. You did some sort of odd self-answering in the post and then asked us a valid question... the first part was completely unnecessary and distracted users to the core question/issue you need help (I am sure that it was the reason for the downvotes, as some mentioned in comments)

Comment: @DarkCygnus yeah I’ve been in industry for the last two years or so and haven’t had the time to use the workplace much. I needed to change my username so I could feel comfortable asking questions while on the job. So I’m super rusty in general. Note, we’ve communicated at length before. But now that I have a new job, I’m considering whether to change my username back to something you’d recognize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this language help?

1. You get a message from B regarding the return of their computers.
2. Respond like this:

> Dear Jim, thanks for the message. Just a reminder that I left some important legal documents and my Walkman in the top drawer of office 713. I've already sent over to your secretary a return box for me to get out of your hair these important papers (and the Walkman!)  Please note too that if you prefer I can just swing by for them. If you want me to do that, just reply, thanks. I can come any time.

Note that you don't say ANYTHING ABOUT their message in "1".  Just "Start talking" about the process of getting back your items.

Note that I am not suggesting or literally even mentioning "not giving back their stuff".

This is "topic ghosting".  Someone picks up the phone and starts talking to you about issue A.  You don't even *mention* issue A in any way; you have *no segue*; you just immediately start talking about your issue B.

Again: I am not even here *giving an opinion* on anything in relation to the laptops (or whatever it is).

When B contacts you (about anything) just "topic ghost" them and immediately re-cap how you are going to get your stuff back.

This is completely normal in the business world. Lawyers, diplomats, etc, essentially do this all the time in formal negotiations.

Comment: Good idea Fattie. I think I’ll go with this.

Comment: @Bluebird - sure, it's the usual solution.  Don't forget (1) be brief and clear (2) ultra- "topic ghost"!  say nothing about their issue, just start typing your issue (3) be "beyond polite" so the notion that you would do something whacky like *delay* returning their laptops is plain inconceivable. (Who me?!)  It is *disgusting* your stuff has not been promptly returned to you.  F*** their laptops, your stuff is probably 100s of thousands of times more relatively valuable to you.  Worker's rights!!!!  Good luck!

Comment: I think that one can be assertive and use the "topic ghost" technique, however, if we add to the end of your prhasing the following, it could be perhaps less ghosty and more assertive: "I can come any time. I can even bring the laptop to handle it over, so we kill two birds with one stone." ... just a suggestion I thought of when reading your answer :)

Comment: Good answer, I do this sometimes (mostly with bills). Get your agenda sorted first before bothering with theirs without making any ultimatums.

Comment: Just note. I’m going to be moving out of state. So an in-person handoff would not be viable.

Comment: @Bluebird it would be appropriate to get your things back before you move.

Comment: @thursdaysgeek I would agree. But with WFH I am already out of state at this exact moment.

Answer (score 1):

> So the question now becomes, should I make it clear that they should ship my stuff back such that they can get theirs back?

No.

If you have their property and they are asking for you to return it, return it.  Keeping it or attempting to use it to receive something in return (i.e. your property) is not only unprofessional, but a crime in most areas.  The professional thing to do is return what does not belong to you.

The fact that they have your belongings that you want back is a totally separate issue.  It would be unprofessional on their part to refuse to return your property or allow you to pick it up in some way.

Comment: Good answer. If you perhaps gave some advice on how to handle or approach the separate issue regarding OP getting their stuff back, while still doing the professional/legal approach you suggest (return laptop), I think your answer would be even better.